# argmax() or idxmax() is not providing right index where the maximum value is located

Tags: python, python-3.x, max, argmax

I have a subset dataframe and am trying to find the index where in the volume column is the max volume. In this case it should be index 1428, but using argmax or idxmcx it is giving 1431

```
combine1
Out[381]: 
       folder                   fn    volume
1428  SF_20141231  IF1501_20141231.csv  162.0000
1429  SF_20141231  IF1502_20141231.csv    4.0000
1430  SF_20141231  IF1503_20141231.csv    6.0000
1431  SF_20141231  IF1506_20141231.csv    7.0000
1432  SF_20141231  TF1503_20141231.csv    4.0000
1433  SF_20141231  TF1506_20141231.csv    0.0000
1434  SF_20141231  TF1509_20141231.csv    0.0000
```

where I would use

```
combine1['volume'].idxmax(axis=0)
Out[385]: 1431

combine1['volume'].argmax()
Out[386]: 1431
```

Both of these are incorrect. How to fix this?

Comment: I guess `volume` is a string and not a number - as that'd make the 7.0000 the largest value there.... make sure you convert it to numerics (maybe using `pd.to_numeric` or whatever is more appropriate)

Comment: that still doesn't work. this is driving me nuts actually...hahaha, I need to find max value and I can't

Answer (score 0):

@user9240544, you need to convert the column to float using to_numeric. See the mockup below:

You notice if you remove the line `combine1['volume'] = pd.to_numeric(combine1['volume'])` you will get 'volume' as string and that is the result you are getting.

```
raw_data = {
    'folder': ['SF_20141231','SF_20141231','SF_20141231','SF_20141231','SF_20141231','SF_20141231','SF_20141231'], 
        'fn': ['IF1501_20141231.csv','IF1502_20141231.csv','IF1503_20141231.csv','IF1506_20141231.csv','TF1503_20141231.csv','TF1506_20141231.csv','TF1509_20141231.csv'], 
        'volume': ['162.0000','4.0000','6.0000','7.0000','4.0000','0.0000','0.0000']}

combine1 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data,index=[1428,1429,1430,1431,1432,1433,1434])
combine1['volume'] = pd.to_numeric(combine1['volume'])
combine1['volume'].idxmax(axis=0)
combine1['volume'].argmax()
```